# How to call method from interface, if object implement this interface?

Tags: c#, collections, interface

I have a collections of elemets

```
 readonly Deposit[] deposits;
```

some of elements in this collection are implement interface

```
interface IProlongable
{
    public bool CanToProlong();
}
```

I need to calculate amount of `true` results that are returned by method in interface

```
public int CountPossibleToProlongDeposit()
    {
        int count = default;
        foreach (var deposit in deposits)
        {
            if (deposit is IProlongable)
            {
                // Here i need to check if deposit.CanToProlog() is true and increment counter.
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Comment: You can call method by doing `deposit.CanToProlong();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (deposit is IProlongable p && p.CanToProlog())
{
    count++;
}
```

When [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) (using `is`) you can cast the result to a variable (here `p`).

`p` is of type `IProlongable` so you have access to the method `CanToProlog()`.

You can also use the `++` operator to increment `count` by 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer) Could you please reccomed which topic i need to lear for this task?

Comment: @saYmon There is a link to the Pattern Matching documentation in my answer. That should explain everything.